# MSDN SetBitmap doesn't work, CButton shows up blank

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, msdn

I'm trying to create a button with a bmp image taken from the resources using `CButton::SetBitmap()`. Using this code:

```
BOOL MyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    __super::OnInitDialog();

    m_myBitmap=::LoadBitmap(AfxGetResourceHandle(),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MY_BITMAP ));
    m_myButton.SetBitmap( m_myBitmap );

    return TRUE;
}
```

But the button shows up gray with no image on it. I verified if my bitmap loaded correctly with GDIPlus saving it into a jpeg and everything seems fine. Why isn't the image showing up on the button?

Comment: The error checking in this code is badly broken, only ever call GetLastError() after a winapi function failed.  It could be accidentally correct, the m_myBitmap variable does not seem to have anything to do with the m_bm variable.  As posted, the code does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. You need to set the `BS_BITMAP` flag on your CButton otherwise nothing happens. Furthermore there seems to be 2 functions that allows you to modify the button style:

```
CButton::ModifyStyle();
CButton::SetButtonStyle();
```

and for some obscure reason `CButton::SetButtonStyle();` wasn't setting the flag correctly for me, hence the confusion.

With correctly loaded resources this worked:

```
BOOL MyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    __super::OnInitDialog();

    m_myBitmap=::LoadBitmap(AfxGetResourceHandle(),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MY_BITMAP ));
    m_myButton.ModifyStyle( 0, BS_BITMAP );
    m_myButton.SetBitmap( m_myBitmap );

    return TRUE;
}
```